# Simplification of fractions in a proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In [https://sites.ualberta.ca/~smartynk/Resources/CMPUT%20272/inductionprobs.pdf](https://sites.ualberta.ca/%7Esmartynk/Resources/CMPUT%20272/inductionprobs.pdf) the following identity is stated, without a justification being given:

$${n^2 + 3n + 2\over 2} = n + 1 + {n^2 + n \over 2 }$$

I do not understand why this equality holds and no justificatin is given in the website above. Can anyone explain how the left-hand side of this equation is simplified to the right-hand side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a basic simplification of fractions,
$$\frac{n^{2}+(2n+n)+2}{2}$$
Split the terms $2n+2$ and $n^2+n$.
$$\frac{n^2+n}{2}+\frac{2(n+1)}{2}$$
Cancelling off those 2, gives us the required expression.